# jQuery TableSorter how to sort text/number from last to first char

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

i have table with one colum show state some day must to show from oldest to newest like (ex):

```
6417127(Mon:6,Tue:4,Wed:1,Thu:7,Fri:1,Sat:2,Sun:7)
6734976
9853385
1378454
6413366
```

how do i sort that colum each value from last char to first char (right to left). I tried to reverse text/number to sort, its ok but then it shows reversed text/number. if i add one more column with reversed values ​​seem funny. so how to sort that but not change orgin value? help me plz!

Comment: share your code which u tried !!!!!

Comment: here the test code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1732/) i dont know how to sort text from last to first char of text colum state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'weekdays', 
        is: function(s) { 
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
            return false; 
        }, 
        format: function(s) { 
            // format your data for normalization 
            return return s.split("").reverse().join("");  
        }, 
        // set type, either numeric or text 
        type: 'text' 
    }); 

    $(function() { 
        $("table").tablesorter({ 
            headers: { 
                0: { 
                    sorter:'weekdays' 
                } 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: +1 This will work (remove the extra `return`), but you might want to parse the value since the column  contains numbers `return parseInt(s.split('').reverse().join(), 10);` - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1735/

Comment: it seem to be not worked with list of number with different lenght, ex  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1736/) but ill try to fix with your code, its helful. if you could update code for me, so thanks very much!